# metafor zero variance level 2

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I'm running into zero variance at level 2 for a 3-level meta-analysis with metafor (rma.mv) in which effect sizes (esid) are clustered within studies (studyid). Here is my dataframe:

```
studyid <- c(1,1,1,1,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,9,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,
             15,15,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,23,23,23,24,24,25,28,28,28,
             29,29,30,30,30,31,32,32,34,34) 
esid <- c(1:77)
yi <- c(4.20,2.90,2.70,3.90,1.40,0.80,11.40,5.00,21.50,20.84,28.73,7.40,4.00,1.38,0.47,1.44,0.46,1.63,
        0.46,0.67,0.41,9.24,9.27,8.80,27.30,22.83,18.25,20.08,0.94,0.97,0.77,0.88,14.00,10.40,0.52,0.86,
        29.39,33.82,15.30,15.92,45.60,63.10,46.40,44.60,0.10,0.11,0.12,0.17,0.26,0.26,0.31,8.20,1.80,
        1.70,9.58,10.15,8.05,0.53,18.95,17.44,23.50,12.62,15.62,4.60,35.10,44.85,33.30,13.30,11.90,0.34,
        0.35,0.26,0.69,0.50,0.62,23.80,20.40)
vi <- c(2.90,2.20,2.10,3.00,2.00,1.00,11.03,8.49,16.97,20.00,26.06,3.70,4.00,0.47,0.33,0.74,0.36,0.75,
        0.33,0.44,0.37,7.60,5.63,8.80,12.01,13.15,14.41,11.57,0.57,0.76,0.43,0.62,3.50,3.00,0.59,0.65,
        10.00,11.30,6.20,6.44,23.04,27.68,17.54,13.04,0.22,0.25,0.24,0.17,0.42,0.17,0.28,7.20,2.00,2.10,
        10.08,5.30,3.75,0.68,6.70,6.53,5.74,13.91,31.65,4.10,7.54,12.81,5.28,8.20,7.70,0.25,0.28,0.19,
        0.56,0.46,0.37,23.10,15.90)
df <- data.frame(authoryr,studyid,esid,yi,vi)
```

Here is my metafor code and output:

```
overall <- rma.mv(yi, vi, 
                      data = df,
                      level = 95,
                      method = "REML", 
                      slab = authoryr, 
                      tdist = TRUE, 
                      random = list(~ 1 | esid, 
                                    ~ 1 | studyid)) 
summary(overall)

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 77; method: REML)

   logLik   Deviance        AIC        BIC       AICc 
-229.2872   458.5745   464.5745   471.5667   464.9078   

Variance Components:

              estim     sqrt  nlvls  fixed   factor 
sigma^2.1    0.0000   0.0000     77     no     esid 
sigma^2.2  147.3645  12.1394     28     no  studyid 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 76) = 1930.1990, p-val < .0001

Model Results:

estimate      se    tval    pval   ci.lb    ci.ub 
 10.7087  2.3165  4.6229  <.0001  6.0951  15.3224  *** 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Visual inspection of the raw effect sizes suggests there is variance within-studies so I'm unsure what is wrong with my data (or code). I'd appreciate any guidance on solutions from the community.

Comment: Note that you forgot to include `authoryr` in the dataset. Not really needed, but then one either has to leave out the `slab = authoryr` line or use `slab = studyid` so that the code actually runs.

Comment: Until the whole world uses R, it remains helpful to flag that that is your language.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Wolfgang and Nick. Apologies, I missed out the authoryr from the dataframe in my original post

Comment: Looking at the plot Wolfgang described it seems that different studies were measuring the effect on wildly different scales. Is there no way of making them more comparable?

Comment: @mdewey the scale is the same for all effects (grams) yet they differ with regard to the methods for clearing mucus in patients with respiratory diseases

Answer (score 2):

There are really large differences between studies, but the estimates within studies do not vary more than one would expect based on their sampling variability alone. See:

```
forest(overall, efac=c(0,0.5))
abline(h=nrow(df) - cumsum(rle(df$studyid)$length) + 0.5, lty="dotted")
```

So it looks perfectly reasonable to me that the estimate of the between-study variance is very large while the estimate of the within-study variance is essentially 0.

Comment: Looking at the forest plot one would have to question what is going on here. Since the OP has not shared with us their scientific question that must remain a mystery.

Comment: @mdewey -  apologies for the excluding the research question; we are interested in the differences between methods for clearing mucus in patients with respiratory diseases.

Comment: @Wolfgang - thanks for the advice re visual inspection of the forest plot.